# change block call order in checkout

Tags: magento-1.7, onepage-checkout

I am trying to integrate sagepay module into my shop mage 1.7 -  http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ebizmarts-sage-pay-suite-ce-sage-pay-approved.html

It works fine with normal 6 step checkout, but I am using a 1 step checkout.

The default checkout calls these blocks in this order:

app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\checkout.xml    is called and then
app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\sagepaysuite.xml

My theme calls them as:

app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\sagepaysuite.xml    is called and then
app\design\frontend\theme\default\layout\onepagecheckout.xml

What sets the order of the blocks and how can I switch the call order to hopefully get this working!

Comment: may try this http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/controlling-block-order

Comment: thanks for that.  I found out it wont solve my actual problem, but I want to know anyway.  If you put as an answer I can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try following codes for controlling block order

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/controlling-block-order

Comment: Please avoid adding one line answers. Add it as a comment or give more details about what is found at that url

Comment: i did that but he said he will accept if i post it as answer :) but sure, i will avoid! am sorry!

Comment: @marius If the comment answers the question, and cant be accepted, then the question remains unanswered when it has been resolved. How does that help?

Comment: @Jon hes right that I should have posted the code for block order directly here. cause links can get unavailable :)